# Dictionary Manipulation Using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

I'm having a Dictionary like

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    {"One",new List<String>{"A","B","C"}},
    {"Two",new List<String>{"A","C","D"}}
};
```

I need to get a `List<String>` from this dictionary, The List should contain Distinct items from the values of the above dictionary.

So the resulting List will contain `{"A","B","C","D"}`.

Now I'm using `for` loop and `Union` operation. Like

```
List<String> MyList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < MyDict.Count; i++)
{
    MyList = MyList.Union(MyDict[MyDict.Keys.ToList()[i]]).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Can any one suggest me a way to do this in LINQ or LAMBDA Expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var items=MyDict.Values.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or an alternative:

```
var items = (from pair in MyDict
             from s in pair.Value
             select s).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Aw, you beat me :p. The Linq questions are always fun.