# C#: LINQ query from dictionary syntax error, despite repeated usage in SO

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to wrap my head around LINQ from Objects, and specifically in dictionaries, and failing abysmally.

I have seen this syntax in a couple of threads on SO:

```
var items = (from pair in m_taskDictionary
    from s in pair.Value
     s).Distinct().ToList();
```

But when I try to compile this, I get a syntax error:
An expression of type 'OperationsPlannerData.OperationsTaskLabeledData' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

What is wrong?  Is my Visual Studio too old?  (boy would THAT not surprise me.)  I'm using VS 2008.

Here's a link to one of the threads that recommends this usage:

[Dictionary Manipulation Using LINQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003260/dictionary-manipulation-using-linq-in-c-sharp)

In a nutshell, here's the problem I want to resolve: I want to find the first item in the dictionary for which a particular field in the Value object matches a given string.  I have the dictionary already, keyed by integers, for one purpose in my application, so I'd rather just use that dictionary.  Various threads in SO suggest using a `List<KeyValuePair<string, OperationsTaskLabeledData>>` object for this.  I could create that object easily enough, but I don't know how to search that structure either.

Comment: What is the type of your Values? Your 2nd from indicates you think it is a list of some type but maybe it's not?

Comment: If you give more concrete code, I can post more accurate code.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a select in your OP, but this answer is for your last paragraph.

```
m_taskDictionary.First(kvp => kvp.Value.WhateverFieldYouNeed == someString);
```

If you want it to return the default value (`null` for reference types) if it does not find a matching element, use `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have a typo on your question but you are missing `select s` part

```
var items = (from pair in m_taskDictionary
    from s in pair.Value
    select s).Distinct().ToList();  // <-- added select here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var items = (from value in m_taskDictionary.Values 
              where value.field == "a given string" 
              select value).Distinct().ToList();
```

where your dictionary is of type

```
 Dictionary<int, CustomObject> m_taskDictionary = new Dictionary<int, CustomObject>();
```

and the `CustomObject` class has a string property called `field` which you're doing your search on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the select:

```
var items = (from pair in m_taskDictionary
    from s in pair.Value
     select s).Distinct().ToList();
```

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b